# HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error (An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis, .net-3.5, windows-7

I receive this error when I view an application.

> HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error (An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.)

.Net framework 2.0, 3.5 and 4 are installed and I am using SQL 2008. Can anyone tell me what the solution is for this error?

Answer (score 122):

This issue is caused by the pipeline mode in your Application Pool setting that your web site is set to.

**Short**

- **Simple way** Change the Application Pool mode to one that has Classic pipeline enabled.
- **Correct way** Your web.config / web app will need to be altered to support Integrated pipelines. Normally this is as simple as removing parts of your web.config.
- **Simple way (bad practice)** Add the following  to your web.config. See http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/validation

  ```
   <system.webServer>
       <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   </system.webServer>
  ```

**Long**
If possible, your best bet is to change your application to support the integrated pipelines. There are a number of changes between IIS6 and IIS7.x that will cause this error. You can find details about these changes here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis-70/.

If you're unable to do that, you'll need to change the App pool which may be more difficult to do depending on your availability to the web server.

- Go to the web server
- Open the IIS Manager
- Navigate to your site
- Click Advanced Settings on the right Action pane
- Under Application Pool, change it to an app pool that has classic enabled.

Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731755(WS.10).aspx for details on changing the App Pool

If you need to create an App Pool with Classic pipelines, take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784(WS.10).aspx

If you don't have access to the server to make this change, you'll need to do this through your hosting server and contact them for help.

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: ***Programmatically*** _How-to_ know if Application Pool mode is **Classic or Integrated** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet Take a look at [system.web.httpruntime.usingintegratedpipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.usingintegratedpipeline.aspx) and check that value at runtime

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm very new to dot net. I resolved my issue through simple way, described above. Thanks again @Kirk

Answer (score 25):

In your web.config, make sure these keys exist:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 12):

I changed my web.config file to use HTTPMODULE in two forms:

IIS: 6

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="Module" type="app.Module,app"/>
</httpModules>
```

IIS: 7.5

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
       <add name="Module" type="app.Module,app"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 9):

Using VS2013 .net 4.5

I had this same issue.

The "Most likely causes" section on the error message page provided the most help. For me. It said "This application defines configuration in the system.web/httpModules section." Then in the "Things you can try" section it said "Migrate the configuration to the system.webServer/modules section."

```
<system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" validate="false" />
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
      </httpHandlers>
      <httpModules>
        <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
      </httpModules>
    </system.web>
```

into the system.webServer section.

```
<system.webServer> 
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v15.1, Version=15.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Hi, I have the similar issue did you remove it from the <system.web> node? and only left it in the <system.webserver> node

Comment: It's been a while but I am sure I removed it from the <system.web> node and pasted it in the <system.webServer> node. Glad it could help!

Comment: Anyone else who uses this should note that the new markup requires a name to be specified in the add tags. Validate = false needed to be removed and impersonate had to be turned off as well in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Delete the originally created site.
2. Recreate the site in IIS
3. Clean solution
4. Build solution

Seems like something went south when I originally created the site.  I hate solutions that are similar to "Restart your machine, then reinstall windows" without knowing what caused the error.  But, this worked for me.  Quick and simple.  Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with IIS 7, Win 7 Enterprise Pack. I have changed the application Pool as in @Kirk answer :

> Change the Application Pool mode to one that has Classic pipeline enabled".but no luck for me.

Adding one more step worked for me.
I have changed the my website's `.NET Frameworkis v2.0` to `.NET Frameworkis v4.0.` in `ApplicationPool`

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I encountered this issue while migrating a IIS6 website into IIS7, in order to fix this issue I used this command line :
`%windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd migrate config "MyWebSite\"`
Make sure to backup your web.config

Answer (score -1):

Set Application pool to classic .NET appool and make sure that Classic .Net apppool working on  Classic managed  piple line .