# Website (Store Front) configuration IIS 7 Issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have a website working fine on another system, but when i tried to configure it on my laptop (Windows 7 , IIS7), It is showing following error on running. I searched alot on internet but unable to fix the issue. Anyone plz help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

after browsing many web pages and trying different solutions i solved the issue by performing following steps

- OPen command window in visual studio and write debug.startwithoutdebugging
- An error page appeared with error 500.22
- I searched solution for error 500.22 on [Following Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370513/http-error-500-22-internal-server-error-an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detect) , added following code in web.config in my case

there are many other good solutions in this post