# HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error An Asp.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode

Tags: iis

I have webpage which has gridview, one of the columns will have a image. When clicked on image it will open the PDF saved on the web server. It was working fine but I am getting below error

"HTTP Error 55.24 - Internal Server Error  An Asp.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode."

I googled and did as suggested  in [HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error (An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370513/http-error-500-22-internal-server-error-an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detect) made sure application pool is classic and webconfig is correct but still I am getting that error when clicked on image which has to open the saved PDF... please help....

[image]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Your error is specifically to do with 'client impersonation'. I had the same error on one machine but not on another. By comparing settings I worked out the difference.

Start IIS Manager. Select the server in the left pane and double click 'Authentication' under the IIS group in the central pane. Select ASP.NET Impersonation and select 'Disable' at the top of the right pane.

Comment: Shane.. thanks for the response..you are right..and there are other reasons for error too... in my case.. IIS was not installed/configured properly which is specific to ISAPI filter...

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, was struggling from past 2 days. You saved me.

Comment: Thank you Shane, this was really helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much @Shane. Just got what I was looking for.

Comment: ASP.NET Imporsonation is disabled and validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" in Web config. But it is still not working. I am using the Default Website in IIS

Comment: Somehow this got changed for me, i went and change the site level configuration and it fixed all the application under it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 9):

please add web.config

```
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/> 
</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is added in my web config but it is still not working. My website in on Default Website in IIS

Answer (score 1):

I changed in my application pool running the site.
 **"Managed Pipline Mode"** from integrated to classic.

right click on your application *pool -> basic settings*.

Answer (score 0):

One may get this error when accessing a wrong path (e.g., on the `url` parameter of an Ajax call), even though all of the other answers suggestions were handled.

For the correct usage of (relative) paths, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4765962/3002584).

Answer (score -2):

Your error is specifically to do with 'client impersonation'. I had the same error on one machine but not on another. By comparing settings I worked out the difference.

Start IIS Manager. Select the server in the left pane and double click 'Authentication' under the IIS group in the central pane. Select ASP.NET Impersonation and select 'Disable' at the top of the right pane.

Then, select the virtual directory and select the 'Authentication'. Anonymous Auth gonna be 'Enabled'