# Web Role internal server error (500.22)

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-compute-emulator

When running the Compute Emulator, I am getting the following error when trying to access the web role:

> HTTP Error 500.22 - Internal Server Error
>
> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated
>   managed pipeline mode.

Screenshot:

[image]

The website runs fine itself.  This only occurs when I run it in the emulator.

I found a good answer for [500.22 problems here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370513/http-error-500-22-internal-server-error-an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected), but surely there must be something wrong with my Azure environment or cloud service?

Thanks

Comment: This may happen if you uninstall Glimpse or other package which removes this setting : 
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>

 on uninstallation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now I am circumventing this problem with the follow `web.config` change:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

It is not the optimal solution.  More about this [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/validation).