# Error while working with HTTP Module - An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, httpmodule

I am getting error when I launch my application.

```
An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
```

I have created an HTTP module which read information from the request header and writes data into cookies. Here is the code.

```
namespace My.Web
{
    public class UserIdModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private HttpApplication httpApp;

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
        }


        private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access
            // request and response properties.
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
            HttpContext context = application.Context;

            //Read header
            string userId = context.Request.Headers["user_id"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                userId = "guest";
            }

            //Create and write cookie
            HttpCookie userCookie = new HttpCookie("userId", userId);
            userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(5);  
            context.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie);
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }
}
```

In my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
    <!-- To register the module for IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 running in Classic mode -->
    <modules>
      <add name="UserIdModule" type="UserIdModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <!-- To register the module for IIS 7.0 running in Integrated mode -->
    <httpModules>
      <add name="UserIdModule" type="UserIdModule"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is the screenshot of the error: [image]

Comment: Check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370513/http-error-500-22-internal-server-error-an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209999/an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected-that-does-not-apply-in-integrated-managed-p

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the Integrated and Classic modes reversed - at least it appears that way from your comments in the config file.

system.web is for the older Classic mode and system.webserver is for Integrated mode.  See the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/355296/109736) for reference.

If you have some configuration settings in one that normally belongs to the other I could see you getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it IIS 7.5 can you try

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
       <add name="UserIdModule"  type="My.Web.UserIdModule"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```