# Integrated managed pipeline mode Error in VS15

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was a user of visual studio 2012 but now i get switched to visual studio 2015.

Newly developed applications are working and running fine on development server but when I open old .Net applications and runs them it's generating error given below:

> An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated
>   managed pipeline mode.

How can I resolve this ? 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Follow the instructions in [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370513/http-error-500-22-internal-server-error-an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected)

Comment: ok thanks it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just Added the following lines in web.config file under configuration TAG :

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the answer in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370513/http-error-500-22-internal-server-error-an-asp-net-setting-has-been-detected)

There are three options to solve this.

1. Change the Application Pool mode to one that has Classic pipeline enabled.
2. In web.config / web app will need to be altered to support Integrated pipelines. Normally this is as simple as removing parts of your web.config.
3. Add the following to your web.config.